# F# assuming int when actually dealing with int64

Tags: f#, type-inference

Going through [Project Euler](http://projecteuler.net/) trying to learn F#, I stumbled upon what appears to be a type inference problem while writing a solution for [problem 3](http://projecteuler.net/problem=3).

Here's what I wrote:

```ml
let rec findLargestPrimeFactor p n = 
    if n = 1 then p
    else
        if n % p = 0 then findLargestPrimeFactor p (n/p)
        else findLargestPrimeFactor (p+1) n

let result = findLargestPrimeFactor 2 600851475143L
```

However, the compiler gives me the following error:

```
error FS0001: This expression was expected to have type    int    but here has type    int64
```

Since I expect the types used in `findLargestPrimeFactor` to be inferred from usage, I'm quite surprised to find out the compiler seems to assume that parameter `n` be an int since in the only call to the function is done with an int64.

Could someone explain to me:

1. why the compiler appears to be confused about types
2. how to work around this limitation

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The types in `findLargestPrimeFactor` are inferred from usage. The F# compiler performs type inference in a top-to-bottom manner, so the types of `p` and `n` (the parameters of `findLargestPrimeFactor`) are inferred from their usage in the function. By the time the compiler sees the `let result = ...`, the parameter types have already been inferred as `int`.

The easiest solution is to use the `L` suffix on all of your constant values, so the types will be inferred as `int64`:

```
let rec findLargestPrimeFactor p n = 
    if n = 1L then p
    else
        if n % p = 0L then findLargestPrimeFactor p (n/p)
        else findLargestPrimeFactor (p + 1L) n

let result = findLargestPrimeFactor 2L 600851475143L
```

If you want a fancier solution, you can use the generic one and zero constants from the `LanguagePrimitives` module. This allows `findLargestPrimeFactor` to be generic(-ish) so it can be reused more easily with different numeric types:

```
open LanguagePrimitives

let rec findLargestPrimeFactor p n = 
    if n = GenericOne then p
    else
        if n % p = GenericZero then findLargestPrimeFactor p (n/p)
        else findLargestPrimeFactor (p + GenericOne) n

(* You can use one of these, but not both at the same time --
   now the types of the _arguments_ are used to infer the types
   of 'p' and 'n'. *)

//let result = findLargestPrimeFactor 2L 600851475143L
let result = findLargestPrimeFactor 2 Int32.MaxValue
```

Per @kvb's suggestion, here's how you can write this function generically:

```
open LanguagePrimitives

let inline findLargestPrimeFactor p n =
    let rec findLargestPrimeFactor p n =
        if n = GenericOne then p
        else
            if n % p = GenericZero then findLargestPrimeFactor p (n/p)
            else findLargestPrimeFactor (p + GenericOne) n
    findLargestPrimeFactor p n

(* Now you can call the function with different argument types
   as long as the generic constraints are satisfied. *)
let result = findLargestPrimeFactor 2L 600851475143L
let result' = findLargestPrimeFactor 2 Int32.MaxValue
```

Comment: Is there a way to write a function so it can be used with any number of types? e.g. if I were to write, say, my own sqrt (for some unfathomable reason), I would like for it to work with `int`, `float`, `bigint`, `decimal`, etc.

Comment: Note that you can make `findLargestPrimeFactor` actually generic by making it inline and moving the recursion into a nested let.

Comment: Sort of -- depending on what you want to implement, you might be able to use [static type constraints](http://tomasp.net/blog/fsharp-generic-numeric.aspx).

Comment: @kvb I'd be interested to see your suggested solution.