# tail recursion and Boolean operators

Tags: f#, tail-recursion

I am currently learning F# on my own (via the try f# site).
I have the following (imho) tail-recursive function for existential quantification of a unary predicate (int->bool).

```
let rec exists bound predicate = 
    if (bound<0) then false
    elif predicate(bound) then true
    else exists (bound-1) predicate
```

Now this function can also be written as

```
let rec exists bound predicate = (bound+1>0) && (predicate(bound) || exists (bound-1) predicate)
```

However, the second implementation is not tail-recursive. The question is whether or not the compiler will optimize it to tail-recursive?

How is the situation for even simpler (ok, it is a bit silly) examples, say

```
let rec hasNoRoot f = 
    if (f x = 0) then false
    else hasNoRoot (fun x -> f (x+1))
```

versus

```
let rec hasNoRoot f = (f 0 <> 0) && (hasNoRoot (fun x-> f(x+1)))
```

in the second example, in order to recognize the function (its description actually) as tail-recursive, the compiler only needs to "know" that in order to evaluate a conjunction, not necessarily both conjuncts have to be evaluated.

thanks for any advice

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can a function be optimized for tail recursion even when there are more than one distinct recursive calls?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15031382/can-a-function-be-optimized-for-tail-recursion-even-when-there-are-more-than-one)

Comment: @Joce While this question has some similarities to yours, it's different enough to warrant keeping it open.

Answer (score 1):

I compiled the second versions of your 'exists' and 'hasNoRoot' functions with VS2012 (F# 3.0) and optimizations on, then checked the IL produced by the compiler using .NET Reflector. The compiler *does* optimize the 'hasNoRoot' function, but unfortunately, does not optimize the 'exists' function. It seems like a reasonable optimization though, so perhaps it will be added to the next version of the compiler.

For posterity, here's what the compiler generated:

```
.method public static bool exists(int32 bound, class [FSharp.Core]Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpFunc`2<int32, bool> predicate) cil managed
{
    .custom instance void [FSharp.Core]Microsoft.FSharp.Core.CompilationArgumentCountsAttribute::.ctor(int32[]) = { new int32[int32(0x2)] { int32(0x1), int32(0x1) } }
    .maxstack 8
    L_0000: nop 
    L_0001: ldarg.0 
    L_0002: ldc.i4.1 
    L_0003: add 
    L_0004: ldc.i4.0 
    L_0005: ble.s L_001c
    L_0007: ldarg.1 
    L_0008: ldarg.0 
    L_0009: callvirt instance !1 [FSharp.Core]Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpFunc`2<int32, bool>::Invoke(!0)
    L_000e: brfalse.s L_0012
    L_0010: ldc.i4.1 
    L_0011: ret 
    L_0012: ldarg.0 
    L_0013: ldc.i4.1 
    L_0014: sub 
    L_0015: ldarg.1 
    L_0016: starg.s predicate
    L_0018: starg.s bound
    L_001a: br.s L_0001
    L_001c: ldc.i4.0 
    L_001d: ret 
}
```